# Updating a Database View in Android

Tags: android, database, view, android-contacts

I have a device which as a view in the Contacts database (Contacts2.db). This device is running ICS.

I want to add a column to this view.

So where can I find the scripts/code where these views are created? OR how do I go about updating the database view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. It sounds to me as if you are trying to change the (private) contacts DB of the contacts app on a rooted device. Let's forget about that I think that's actually a pretty bad idea. There is no ALTER VIEW command in SQLite so you cannot extend an existing view. You can only drop and re-create views, if that is what you really want to do. You might as well just create your own view which contains that additional column and make use of that. Be aware that apps are not supposed to have direct access to these DBs. Use content providers instead.

Comment: Hi Nobu, Thanks for that. I'm actually working on a content provider and adding some additional functionality to the device with a different type of contacts.

Comment: And the device/board is pretty much production hardware... So I can do whatever I want ;-)

Comment: That's a perfect scenario of course :-D ... basically you are looking for the original (SQL) source code that creates these tables so you can change that? Have you tried a text search in your source code for CREATE VIEW code containing the columns you know?

Comment: Git it! ContactsDatabaseHelper.java ;-)